# Where has the menu item for downloading games and apps gone in the Jessie update of Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, raspbian-jessie, games

Before the Jessie update, I was able to add games using some kind of installer that I could access from the start menu. Now it's gone.

Where can I find these games and apps at SS to download them like I used to?

Comment: A little more detail about this installer would be great. Have you tried doing a Google search?

Comment: @darthvader, and Grant Winney... I apologize,  but I don't remember the name of the installer. However,  the distro that I remember it was in Wheezy. I know this is seriously vague, but that's all I remember. I have no screen grabs,  because I don't know how to on rpi,  and I also didn't think that this utility would have been removed. The only Google search I have come up with was people using the terminal to get them,  but I used something different that allowed me to download them after looking at them similar to looking at the Google play store. But it was built into the distro.

Comment: I think you are looking for pistore. I don't think it exists anymore. You could try sudo apt-get install pistore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the information I found about pistore
 https://www.raspberrypi.org/pi-store-shutdown/

Comment: You're correct sir. Thank you very much. This is in fact what I was looking for. Although it's sad that they closed it down. I did try the sudo command and it didn't work